# php sort an object by two criteria?

Tags: php, object, sorting

Trying to sort this array of objects according to (1) depth and (2) weight, and am unsure how to modify the function I'm using to include this other level...

I'm using this function:

```
function cmp( $a, $b ) {
    if(  $a->weight ==  $b->weight ){
        return 0 ;
    }
    return ($a->weight < $b->weight) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

And then doing this:

```
$menu = get_tree(4, $tid, -1, 2);
usort($menu, 'cmp');
```

And that will accurately sort the array according to weight, but I need to add in another level of sorting.  So that the array is first sorted according to depth, and then by weight.

So that, if the original array looks like this:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 24
            [name] => Sample
            [weight] => 3
            [depth] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 66
            [name] => Sample Subcategory
            [weight] => 0
            [depth] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 67
            [name] => Another Example
            [weight] => 1
            [depth] => 0
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 68
            [name] => Subcategory for Another Example
            [weight] => 1
            [depth] => 1
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 22
            [name] => A third example master category
            [weight] => 0
            [depth] => 0
        )
```

I can sort it first by depth, then by weight so that the result looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 22
            [name] => A third example master category
            [weight] => 0
            [depth] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 67
            [name] => Another Example
            [weight] => 1
            [depth] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 24
            [name] => Sample
            [weight] => 3
            [depth] => 0
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 66
            [name] => Sample Subcategory
            [weight] => 0
            [depth] => 1
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 68
            [name] => Subcategory for Another Example
            [weight] => 1
            [depth] => 1
        )
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function cmp( $a, $b )
{
  if ($a->depth == $b->depth)
  {
    if($a->weight == $b->weight) return 0 ;
    return ($a->weight < $b->weight) ? -1 : 1;
  }
  else
    return ($a->depth < $b->depth) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

when comparing numbers, you can simply subtract them

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
   $d = $a->depth - $b->depth;
   return $d ? $d : $a->weight - $b->weight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has made great improvements since the year 2010.  For this task, the PHP7 "spaceship operator" or "three-way comparison operator" can be used to craft a one-line comparison in the `usort()` call.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/X7dG9))

```
usort($menu, function($a, $b) {
    return [$a->depth, $a->weight] <=> [$b->depth, $b->weight];
});
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  (object) array(
     'tid' => 22,
     'name' => 'A third example master category',
     'weight' => 0,
     'depth' => 0,
  ),
  1 => 
  (object) array(
     'tid' => 67,
     'name' => 'Another Example',
     'weight' => 1,
     'depth' => 0,
  ),
  2 => 
  (object) array(
     'tid' => 24,
     'name' => 'Sample',
     'weight' => 3,
     'depth' => 0,
  ),
  3 => 
  (object) array(
     'tid' => 66,
     'name' => 'Sample Subcategory',
     'weight' => 0,
     'depth' => 1,
  ),
  4 => 
  (object) array(
     'tid' => 68,
     'name' => 'Subcategory for Another Example',
     'weight' => 1,
     'depth' => 1,
  ),
)
```

Writing `$a` properties in the left array and `$b` properties on the right will sort ASC; reverse these respective positions to use DESC directional sorting.

Extension: If you want to sort by: `$weight` DESC, then `$name` ASC, then `$depth` DESC, write the array of comparison criteria like this:

```
[$b->weight, $a->name, $b->depth] <=> [$a->weight, $b->name, $a->depth]
```

---

From PHP7.2, another technique can be used: `array_multisort()` and multiple calls of `array_column()`. Before 7.2, `array_column()` could not be used on objects.)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/I0tCg))

```
array_multisort(array_column($menu, 'depth'), array_column($menu, 'weight'), $menu);
```

To mirror the criteria in my earlier "Extension", the syntax gets a bit longer because each column requires its own `array_column()` call and sorting directions need to be expressed.

```
array_multisort(array_column($menu, 'weight'), SORT_DESC, array_column($menu, 'name'), array_column($menu, 'depth'), SORT_DESC, $menu);
```